# Long press menu button (for Samsung Galaxy S i9000)

Tags: android

How can I intercept menu button long press, in order to launch my app ?
Is there any configuration in manifest.xml able to do this ?

Thank you.

A.L.

Comment: I'm looking for the same. Did you find a solution elsewhere already?

Comment: Not for the moment, I'm still looking for an issue !